# Why Hibernate Lazy loading acts different in Kotlin?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

[Here is a simple example](https://github.com/mullema4/hibernate-test/blob/jointcolumn-mappedby/src/main/java/com/example/hibernatetest/HibernateTestService.java) of `@OneToOne` entity mapping using Java 11, Spring Boot 2.4.5 and Hibernate 5.4.29.

In Java implementation Lazy loading works fine - only `Post` entity is loaded:

```sql
select id, details_id from post
```

[Here is the same code](https://github.com/mullema4/hibernate-test/blob/kotlin-issue/src/main/java/com/example/hibernatetest/HibernateTestService.kt) in Kotlin. It produces following SQL:

```sql
select id, details_id from post

select pd.id, p.id, p.details_id
from post_details pd
    left outer join post p on pd.id = p.details_id
where pd.id = ?

select p.id, p.details_id from post p
where p.details_id = ?
```

I do not understand what is wrong here. Mapping is the same but `LAZY` is ignored. Moreover the bidirectional association is loaded twice - one SELECT from each side.

---

SOLUTION UPDATE

In addition to [Lukes's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67131596/2431410) solution I would like to point out one Kotlin confusion: [`kotlin-jpa`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/no-arg-plugin.html#jpa-support) plugin is surprisingly not enough to make JPA/Hibernate work properly. We had to configure [`kotlin-spring`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support) plugin (which is a wrapper for `all-open` plugin) and configure it to make @Entity open. This way, Hibernate can finally create proxy allowing lazy loading.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Luke the code is in links given in post...

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by kotlin classes. In order to fix it do as follow:

In your `build.gradle` plugins section:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version <kotlinVersion>
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version <kotlinVersion>
}
```

and at bottom of file

```
allOpen {
    annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
    annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
    annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
}
```

this should fix the problem

Comment: Plugins are already there but annotation configuration is missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've also noticed that the Kotlin scope function `with()` will perform eager loading of lazy-loaded properties on the class.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
open var chapters: MutableSet<Chapter> = mutableSetOf()
```

Using the `with()` function

```
with(bookRepository.findById(bookId)) {
  assertNotNull(this)
}
```

The chapters will be loaded eagerly. Whereas the following doesn't:

```
val book: Book? = bookRepository.findById(bookId)
assertNotNull(book)
```